# how to reduce the length of a block in a frame

Tags: beamer

I would like to reduce the length of a block in a frame because it is too long respect to the instance it contains. How is it possible?

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the block inside a `minipage` or a `columns` environment and use the desired width; a little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Test}
test
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
\begin{exampleblock}{Test}
test
\end{exampleblock}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]